# Getting 404 Not Found connecting to webDAV

Tags: c#, webdav

I am trying to connect to a secure webDAV folder and download a file. I am having problems just trying to get a response from the server and as it keeps giving me a 404 Not Found error as soon as I call Request.GetResponse(). I can connect to the webDAV folder using Windows Explorer by mapping a drive but cannot seem to do this in code. I have looked at other post on this site and others online but most seem to concentrate on connecting to Outlook. Has anybody else had this issue? The code I am using is as follows:

```
string URI = "https://transfer.mycompany.com/myDirectory/myFile.csv";
string username = "username";
string password = "password";
Request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(URI);
Request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
Request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
Request.Headers.Add("Translate", "f");
Response = (HttpWebResponse) Request.GetResponse();
contentLength = Convert.ToInt64(Response.GetResponseHeader("Content-Length"));
```

Comment: WebDAV = HTTP + extra features. The functionality you're using doesn't use any of the extra features.

I would suggest just trying to open the url in a browser. Does it work? Does it exist?

Comment: Get the same error 404 Not Found when trying to access it through a browser. Its not my webDAV so can not look into its set up and config.

Comment: That tells you that you are using the incorrect url. First try to figure out what the url should have been in the browser, and then go back to your C# code.

Comment: I am told by the owner of the webDAV server (backed up with screenshot) that they can connect with the exact same URL using web folders connection on XP IE6. I tried this in my VPC and still get 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Fiddler tool](http://fiddlertool.com) to see what else headers are sent to the server, when you access it from Windows Explorer. Try adding these headers to your code to make it more similar to the request sent by WindowsExplorer and see if this helps.

Comment: Had a look but its over https and although fiddler does seem to decrypt this there is nothing much in the http headers for me to see. But good suggestion though, thanks.